# How i can convert my variables to regualr date format in excel

Tags: excel, sas

the date variable is showing as per my attached image . When I am importing it to SAS my date variable is reading by SAS as a categorical variable . How I can convert that date values in standard format (yyyy-mm-dd) in excel so sas can read it correctly . Thank you for your help .

[date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0wWj.png)

Comment: That's because it looks like you have invalid dates in the column so when SAS is guessing at types, it doesn't assume that those are dates. You can modify it in Excel and try and import it, or you can convert your file to CSV and read it in correctly (best method) or you can import it as is, and fix after the fact using INPUT().

Comment: What is that a picture of?  That one column seems to have three different types of values, character strings, dates, and numbers that might be unformatted Excel date values.  You can get away with that in a spreadsheet, but it will not work as a dataset.

Comment: What do you mean "categorical" value? Dates are by definition categorical. They have discrete finite values.

Comment: @Tom Presumably the SAS VA / etc. definition (Categorical, Measure, Text, Date, Datetime)?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Select your column and click where the picture shows, and click on 'Date' (short or long date).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting it after the fact.

Assuming your dates are coming in as YYYY-MM-DD. What do you want to do with the 9999-99-999 or 354332 values? [Input](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm&locale=da#p1bgiwvfo9omgzn14iubq0zojvax) will assign them as missing and `?` suppresses NOTES about invalid data.

```
data want;
   set dataImported;

    *use ?? to suppress the errors in the log;
    newDate = input(address_date_changed, ? yymmdd10.);
    format newDate yymmddd10.;

run;

*check output;
proc print data=want (obs=100) label noobs;
where not missing(newDate);
var newDate;
run;
```